# How to display a magic variable in a display form?

Tags: docker, processmaker

I'm attempting to add the _user.fullname variable in to a display form (readonly), but I'm not seeing an easy way to do this. Using this variable name isn't allowed directly on a line input for example.  Am I missing something basic here?

Thanks in advance.
ProcessMaker v4.2.30

Answer (score 0):

For those that have the same query, its quite simple.

Use the "Calcs" button at the top of the screen where you want to show the variable, and create a new "property name" with the formula

`_user.fullname`